# special prices are showing only in product list page in one magento site

Tags: price, special-price

price.phtml = >http://pastebin.com/T8xhyqp7

we used above code to display price and special price in produt list and product view page.

but in one site, this above code is working fine in product list and product view page,

but in another page, it's working only in product list page.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that the Special Price attribute is set to be visible on product listing

Comment: @swiss_blade thanks a lot for support, i got solution , i posted solution .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this fixed it: Promotions > Catalog Price Rule > YOUR RULE > Actions > Enable Discount to Subproducts > YES >set the discount exactly the same as you did above it.